# Which is more idiomatic: positional arguments or option hashes?

Tags: ruby, methods, variable-assignment

I'm new to Ruby and I've seen constructors done a couple different ways, and I'm curious which is the more idiomatic way? These are the 2 most common variations I've seen:

**Straight assignment:**

```
class Foo

  attr_accessor :id
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(id, name)
    @id = id
    @name = name
  end

end
```

**Hash passing:**

```
class Foo

  attr_accessor :id
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(options)
    @id = options[:id]
    @name = options[:name]
  end

end
```

Which is most idiomatic, or is there an alternative way I've not covered here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Arity of Method Signatures

What you're calling "straight assignment" is really just a method signature with positional arguments. Assignment from hash arguments is something you see a lot of in legacy code because Ruby interpreters prior to version 2.0 didn't have [keyword arguments](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Keyword+Arguments), and option hashes were a good way to simulate them.

Neither is more idiomatic; each has different use cases. Generally, positional arguments are better when you want to enforce the arity of the method, and option hashes are better when you want to avoid complex, order-dependent signatures and are willing to handle nils and arity issues yourself.

### Use Explicit Signatures for Clarity

If you're using Ruby 2.0 or higher, I recommend sticking with positional or keyword arguments to make your method signatures explicit. As an added bonus, explicit signatures with good variable names reduce the amount of documentation you need to write; tools like [RDoc](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc) will document expressive signatures well, but option hashes are rarely self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The first way (Straight Assignment) is more idiomatic, unless you are passing a list of options which may or may not be used.

An alternative is to inherit from an instance of `Struct`:

```
class Foo < Struct.new(:id, :name)
end
```

This is not idiomatic, but I like it because it conveys the power ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is more idiomatic than the other, in my experience.

But here's an approach I like a lot, because it's so flexible and evolvable:

```
def initialize(options = {})
  @id = options.fetch(:id, SOME DEFAULT VALUE)
  etc...
end
```

Comment: Right, yea, I left out the default arguments for simplicity.

Comment: Its a matter of taste, surely, but I generally use options.fetch(:id,<some default value>) just so im in the habit of it, since it cleanly handles the cases when you need to allow booleans in the params hash.

Comment: another option is ruby 2.0 keyword arguments